# google chart discrete axis show line?

Tags: google-visualization

I'm using google charts with discrete values and can't seem to get the vAxis line to be drawn (in black).

It appears when graphic in Continuous values but I don't want the chart to be spaced out that way.

here are the 2 types of graphs.

http://jsfiddle.net/cFHJY/

```
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages: ["corechart"]});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
    var discreteData = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    discreteData.addColumn('string', 'Number');
    discreteData.addColumn('number', 'Value');

    discreteData.addRows([
        ['1.492', 10],
        ['30.701', 17],
        ['127.469', 6],
        ['749.382', 11]
    ]);

    var discreteChart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('discrete_chart_div'));
    discreteChart.draw(discreteData, {
        title: 'Discrete Axis Line Chart'
    });

    var continuousData = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    continuousData.addColumn('number', 'Number');
    continuousData.addColumn('number', 'Value');

    continuousData.addRows([
        [1.492, 10],
        [30.701, 17],
        [127.469, 6],
        [749.382, 11]
    ]);

    var continuousChart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('continuous_chart_div'));
    continuousChart.draw(continuousData, {
        title: 'Continuous Axis Line Chart'
    });
}
```

How do I get the vAxis line to be drawn?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "vAxis line" is actually the hAxis baseline, which is only available to continuous axes.  With a bit of hackery, you can put your data on a continuous axis while appearing to keep its discrete nature.  Use a DataView to convert your data to a "number" type (using the row index for the value and the string value as the formatted value) and build the `hAxis.ticks` option from the value/formatted value pairs in the view:

```
function drawChart() {
    var discreteData = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    discreteData.addColumn('string', 'Number');
    discreteData.addColumn('number', 'Value');

    discreteData.addRows([
        ['1.492', 10],
        ['30.701', 17],
        ['127.469', 6],
        ['749.382', 11]
    ]);

    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(discreteData);
    view.setColumns([{
        type: 'number',
        label: discreteData.getColumnLabel(0),
        calc: function (dt, row) {
            return {v: row + 1, f: dt.getFormattedValue(row, 0)};
        }
    }, 1]);

    var ticks = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < view.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
        ticks.push({v: view.getValue(i, 0), f: view.getFormattedValue(i, 0)});
    }

    var range = view.getColumnRange(0);
    var offset = 0.5; // change this to move the left/right margins of the chart

    var discreteChart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('discrete_chart_div'));
    discreteChart.draw(view, {
        title: 'Discrete Axis Line Chart',
        hAxis: {
            ticks: ticks,
            viewWindow: {
                min: range.min - offset,
                max: range.max + offset
            },
            // set gridlines.color to "transparent" to hide the vertical gridlines
            /*
            gridlines: {
                color: 'transparent'
            }
            */
        }
    });
}
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['corechart'], callback: drawChart});
```

Ex: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/h4Kfd/